# How are SQL Server timeout exceptions handled in Ajax post backs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, exception

I have an Ajax postback within which I make a SQL Server query. The structure's a little too complex to post here. If I have customErrors=Off", then the error is returned to the client in the HTTP response, from whence I pull it out and display the appropriate things to the user:

> 114|error|500|Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding.|

I have other "application exceptions" which I also catch at the client in the same way. All this is free: asp.net puts the above stuff in the http response without my assistance.

I then switch customErrors=On, because in other circumstances I don't want to show a full stack dump to users. At this point all my exceptions as above are stripped of the message, so they become simply:

> 0|error|500||

Which is entirely reasonable. So I then add some exception handling within my Ajax postback code to trap the Application errors... and then I explicitly write the exception data I need back to the client:

> 39|error|202|You do not have access to this record. |

This all works well.

The problem then is with one particular type of exception - SQL Server database timeouts. These appear to be generic "unhandled exceptions", with the database timeout exception inside them. The catch is that this exception doesn't hit my handler at all - I can't find it and report what I want!

Looking at the exception traces, the timeout trace is of course longer than my "you have no access" trace, because it binds several things before it hits my (forced for test purposes) timeout. Looking at just the last bits of the two traces, I have (application eception):

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ApplicationException: You do not have access to this record.
       at pages_***.HideEventLists(Boolean becauseNotAccessible) in *
       at pages_**.AjaxTabLoad(Object sender, AjaxTabEventArgs e) in *
       at userControls_tabs.panel_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in *
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

Versus (SQL Server timeout):

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
```

So I'm wondering where precisely I should be trapping that SQL Server timeout exception? I don't really want to wrap every database access with it's own handler! Is there something I can do to get this exception passed the same way as my application exception?

Comment: Did you try adding a handler on Application_Error on Global.asax?

Comment: No, I wondered about that - I'll give it a try if there's no obvious better way. Not sure why it doesn't hit the expected flow, but I guess it'll end up right up there. I'll report back if that works, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it ends up in ApplicationError, so putting a handler in there works. I'll try page error as that may work too and would be less "global".

Comment: Page error didn't work, not sure why, but ApplicationError does. So I catch the timeouts at that level and write my own HTTP status code and text back. So now my users will get a YSOD and "unknown error" for general exceptions, but they will see my own "the database timed out" error in that specific case.

Comment: try setting EnableViewStateMac to false